# ¿Como puedo agrupar un array de objecto por meses?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, reduce

Tengo un problema al intentar agrupar un array de objetos y sumar sus valores:

```
 let data = [
        {
            nombre: "jose",
            cantidad: 3,
            fecha: "2021-05-01",
        },
        {
            nombre: "carla",
            cantidad: 5,
            fecha: "2021-05-03",
        },
        {
            nombre: "maria",
            cantidad: 8,
            fecha: "2021-05-03",
        },
        {
            nombre: "antonio",
            cantidad: 6,
            fecha: "2021-06-01",
        },
        {
            nombre: "roberto",
            cantidad: 1,
            fecha: "2021-08-01",
        },
        {
            nombre: "jose",
            cantidad: 7,
            fecha: "2021-06-01",
        },
    ];
```

Tengo estos datos y quisiera saber como podría agruparlo por meses sin importar los días, y agrupar los nombre relacionados con ese mes y por último sumar las cantidades de los meses coincidentes.

Esto tiene que darme como respuesta.

```
        let data = [
        {
            cantidad: 16,
            mes: "05",
            personas: [
                { nombre: "jose" },
                { nombre: "maria" },
                { nombre: "carla" },
            ],
        },
        {
            mes: "06",
            cantidad: 13,
            personas: [{ nombre: "jose" }, { nombre: "antonio" }],
        },
        {
            mes: "08",
            cantidad: 1,
            personas: [{ nombre: "roberto" }],
        },
    ];
```

He intentado de construirlo, pero no me sale, hasta aquí llegue.

```
    const result = dat.reduce((ac, el) => {
        const existe = ac.find((e) => e.nombre === el.nombre);
        if (!existe) {
            ac.push({ ...el, cantidad: +el.cantidad });
        } else {
            ac.push({ ...el, cantidad: el.cantidad + existe.cantidad });
        }
        return ac;
    }, []);
```

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Comment: lo primero, tu fecha es un string, tendrias que convertirlo a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), lo segundo, lo que quieres es un json multidimensional así que probablemente necesites iterar el objeto para crearlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver esto con `.reduce` se puede guardar en el acumulador por un lado el criterio y por otro el resultado `[[criterio],[resutado]]` asi:

```js
let data = [{"nombre":"jose","cantidad":3,"fecha":"2021-05-01"},{"nombre":"carla","cantidad":5,"fecha":"2021-05-03"},{"nombre":"maria","cantidad":8,"fecha":"2021-05-03"},{"nombre":"antonio","cantidad":6,"fecha":"2021-06-01"},{"nombre":"roberto","cantidad":1,"fecha":"2021-08-01"},{"nombre":"jose","cantidad":7,"fecha":"2021-06-01"}];

 const res = data.reduce((p, c) => {

   let m = c.fecha.split("-")[1]; // --> Quizá mejor con Date

   let idx = p[0].indexOf(m);

   if (idx > -1) {

     p[1][idx].cantidad += c.cantidad;
     p[1][idx].personas.push(({
       nombre: c.nombre
     }));

   } else {

     p[0].push(m);

     let tmp = {
       cantidad: c.cantidad,
       mes: m,
       personas: [{
         nombre: c.nombre
       }, ],
     }

     p[1].push(tmp);


   }

   return p;
 }, [ [], [] ])[1]; // -->  Para el resultado nos interesa solo segundo elemento

 console.log(res);
```

El mes quiza debería extraerse de un objeto `Date` creado a partir del string.

Comment: Perfecto, lo acabo de probar y además lo pase a **Date** y si me está trayendo el mismo resultado, gracias por el apoyo.